# Set new default file manager for firefox in Archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, firefox

I'm trying to use Dolphin as file chooser for Firefox in Archlinux instead of Nautilus. I've read [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=87574) but it did not solve my problem. The config seems related to firefox as

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory
dolphin.desktop
```

Which is right. Also

```
cat /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache | grep  x-directory/gnome-default-handler
x-directory/gnome-default-handler=kde4-dolphin.desktop;
```

Seems to be right too. What am I missing?

Comment: Admittedly, I'm not sure about this at all, but does X need to be restarted before those changes take effect?

Comment: @HalosGhost I have not restarted X. Just firefox, I will double check on this one.

Comment: Just restarted X no change at all.

Comment: Which file chooser are you referring to? The one you see when using File -> Open or when you're trying to save a file? I don't think you can change that, that's the file chooser dialog provided by Gtk.

Comment: @Wieland the one from file open...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `about:config` in the address bar

Search for `ui.allow_platform_file_picker`

Toggle it to **true**

Restart Firefox.

Comment: I've checked that this is set to true but options remain the same.

Comment: This solution no longer works in Firefox 53.

Comment: I don't have this entree.

Answer (score 10):

Currently (2018-09-25) there exists no user-configurable way to change this behaviour in Firefox.

This is a known bug: [Firefox does not use default file manager](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1285711)

It was first reported on Bugzilla on 2016-07-08.
At the time of writing this bug is unassigned and unresolved.

Answer (score 5):

I'd have a similar problem running Manjaro 4.18.9-1. After install nautilus for a test, firefox started to open folders with nautilus, I removed nautilus and firefox then opened folders with Atom.

At least for me, this solution worked:

- Close firefox
- Go to your file manager (Thunar in my case), right click on a folder and click on "open as"
- Mark "use this app as default" and choose your file manager
- Open firefox and see if it worked

Comment: I don't have "open as" in Thunar context menu.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox use GIO's GAppInfo. GIO's behaviour is slightly different from xdg-mime's. 
By adding `inode/directory=ranger.desktop` in `$HOME/.config/mimeapps.list`, my firefox can open directory properly.

You can check the diffents between `xdg-mime query default inode/directory` and `gio mime inode/directory`.

Comment: This is what I wanted. Great first post!

Comment: Does not work. My mimeapps.list already contains correct filemanager association. Output of `gio mime inode/directory` shows pcmanfm-qt.desktop (which is my correct default filemanager)

Comment: Does not work with Firefox 99.0.1