# How to set nemo as default file explorer in i3 desktop?

Tags: i3, nemo

I use i3 desktop on Arch linux and I use nemo as file explorer.
When in any application I use the option of show in file explorer, it pops up a browser window loading `file://path/to/folder`.

I'd like to configure system to use nemo instead.

Comment: See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_applications, http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146904/136629

Answer (score -2):

You can call nemo with --no-desktop option:

```
nemo --no-desktop
```

Comment: This is a workaround and not a solution to change the default application for the mime type.